# Cant Connect to remote MySQL db from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, centos8

I install docker in a centos 8 VPS. I have the MySQL server running on my VPS. While my container tries to connect the MySQL server, the error has occurred.

`Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.15.0.5' (115)`

This my docker version

```
docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.5
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.12.12
Git commit:        633a0ea
Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:25:41 2019
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false
Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
 Version:          19.03.5
 API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.12.12
 Git commit:       633a0ea
 Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:24:18 2019
 OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 Experimental:     false
containerd:
 Version:          1.2.6
 GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
runc:
 Version:          1.0.0-rc8
 GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
docker-init:
 Version:          0.18.0
 GitCommit:        fec3683
```

When I installed the latest docker-engine same error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow masquerading on firewalld

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Refer [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8/1028508#1028508) explanation.